# Convert hex to decimal in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, r, pandas

I am trying to move from R to python pandas.  I am not an expert and would welcome help.  I have searched!  I have a dataframe, `sh_tags` in R with a  column `thumbs_id` which is in hex.  I convert it to decimal like this:

```
sh_tags$thumb_id <- as.integer(paste("0x",sh_tags$thumbs, sep=""))
```

I can convert a single cell in pandas like this:
`int(thumb_id .iloc[1,0],16)`

But I want to do the column.

Answer (score 6):

For a `Series`:

```
x = pd.Series(["ff","cd","1a"])
b16 = lambda x: int(x,16)
x.apply(b16)
```

seems to work